# Some one please help explain this javascript code, ie whats happening and whats the code doing

Tags: javascript

I am unsure of what this code means, a friend gave it to me to function in making a colour fade in and fade out. But I would like to know what each bit does?

```
lerp = function(a, b, u) {
      return (1 - u) * a + u * b;
};


fade = function(element, property, start, end, duration) {
    var interval = 10;
    var steps = duration / interval;
    var step_u = 1.0 / steps;
    var u = 0.0;
    var theInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (u >= 1.0) {
            clearInterval(theInterval)
        }
        var r = parseInt(lerp(start.r, end.r, u));
        var g = parseInt(lerp(start.g, end.g, u));
        var b = parseInt(lerp(start.b, end.b, u));
        var colorname = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
        element.style.setProperty(property, colorname);
        u += step_u;
    }, interval);
};
```

Comment: you can ask same to your friend no need to post it on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lerp is a function that calculates a value (u) between two values (a, b), by percentage (0 - 1). 
interval is how slowly it updates, then it calculates how many steps in between the two colors there are (steps); then it gets the amount to increment the percentage between colors (step_u).
u is the percentage between the colors, it uses setInterval to make a loop with interval milliseconds between each loop, then it checks if it should
end the loop if it is done fading and uses clearInterval to stop.
then it defines r, g, b as the color values inbetween start and stop, then sets the elements color as the rgb color; then it increments u.

Comment: could you explain it in terms of what is happening? I'm aware of lerp but don't understand what role it is playing within this function.

Comment: @john1214 Every 10 ms, it calls `lerp` with an increasing value of `u`, so it gets the next higher step of the color values.

Comment: @Barmar and what does the equation on the return of the lerp mean?

Comment: That's what he explained in his answer. It returns a number between `a` and `b`, scaled by the fraction in `u`. So if `a = 10, b = 15, u = 0.2`, it returns `11`.

Comment: If you've taken high school algebra, you should be able to figure out the equation.

Comment: @john1214 It's equivalent to `a + (u * (b - a))`.

Comment: okay yeah, i get it. It's just about getting it to click a lot of the time.